# How to create element for each file in a directory | Javascript | NodeJS | EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I want to be able to make a

for every file inside a directory, using ejs in a nodeJS-app.
For now, I have the method, I think:

```
<div class="container">
    <% fs.readdir(dirname, (err, files) => { %>
        <%  files.forEach(file => { %>
            <p> test</p>
        <% }); %>
    <%  }); %>
 </div>
```

I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: /workspace/Web-Dev-Course/filename.ejs:13
    11| </p>
    12| <div class="container">
 >> 13|     <% fs.readdir(dirname, (err, files) => { %>
    14|         <%  files.forEach(file => { %>
    15|             <p> test</p>
    16|         <% }); %>

fs is not defined
```

In the app.js, I have

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const fs = require ('fs');
var dirname = './testdir';
```

And as a check, inside of app.js, I check whether `dirname` can be accessed. (it can!)
How would I fix that error?

Later on, I'll want to add XML files to the directory and have transformations performed, in case that changes anything about the method.

best wishes,
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.ejs` file doesn't have visibility of variables in the `.js` file unless you explicitly send them to the render function along with the path of the view you want to render..

Take this example as guide:

`res.render('index', { fs: fs });`

---

Edit:
If you're programming a browser app, not electron or other technology...

You need to remember that `.ejs` templates compile to Javascript on the other end, so throwing fs module onto the template isn't a wise idea (because it'll not work if used in the template, accessing drive info client side isn't going to work).

I'd therefore recommend you load this data on the server (if you're looking to retrieve the directory data from the server that is not the client).

Here's an example, in your controller do the following:

```
fs.readdir(dirname, (err, files) => {
    res.render('index', { files: files });
});
```

Now modify your view to:

```
<%  files.forEach(file => { %>
    <p> test</p>
<% }); %>
```

Comment: okay, adding the variables fixed it. However, the div is not entered and there is no paragraph not added to the view.

Comment: @kev1807 This is very little information, there's a lot possible problems you may have now and unfortunately you need to debug it yourself. Start by checking if you actually have `dirname` variable passed to your view. What the `fs.readdir` method returns for `dirname`. What `file.forEach` returns if anything at all.

Comment: Okay, so here's a working example of my app.js (reduced a little) [link](https://pastebin.com/W39nzZp2)
and the working example of the .ejs [link](https://pastebin.com/kb8Nf553)

I am at the beginning of my JS-journey, in case you did not notice :-D

Comment: I've not noticed, no :) Unfortunately, Stackoverflow isn't a debugging website, you'll need to do this part yourself as there's too many unknowns from my side (environment and parameter wise). Come back when you've got more details about your next issue and ask another question. I've answered your initial question already. My tip is to put breakpoints and step-through code (not sure if you can debug .ejs files this way, I've never used it).

Comment: I have no experience in debugging :-D 
I changed the function to somehow represent error handling ([link](https://pastebin.com/LPSc7YW6) so that I see, which files are listed (1.xml and 2.xml, very elaborate, I know ...) 

Unfortunately I do not get any errors. :-/